# How to add thumbnails to modal images

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

Question: How can I make a modal image use a thumbnail? Not the original image as the thumbnail, because I have specific images to use as thumbnails.

I am currently trying to make a small 5 picture gallery in a page for my website. So far I have a gallery that does the following:

- When thumbnail is pressed the full size image appears in a new window

I would like my image to appear in front of the page, without leaving the gallery.

I have researched and found out how to implement a modal image in my gallery.

As you can see below in the last image I implemented a modal function.

With this modal function I am able to take an image and make it the size of a thumbnail and once clicked it becomes larger and the screen becomes gray. In itself it is doing what I want it to do, except for the part where the I want a different image as a thumbnail and a different image as the full size image that appears.

```html
  <div id="content">  
        <div class="imageRow">
            
            <div class="single">
                <a href="images/examples/image-prints-1.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="">
                 <img src="images/examples/thumbs-prints-1.jpg" alt=""/></a><br /> 
            </div>      
                  
            <div class="single">
                <a href="images/examples/image-prints-2.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="">
                    <img src="images/examples/thumbs-prints-2.jpg" alt="" /></a><br /> 
            </div>
            
            <div class="single">
                <a href="images/examples/image-prints-3.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="">
                    <img src="images/examples/thumbs-prints-3.jpg" alt="" /></a><br /> 
            </div>

            <div class="single">
                <a href="images/examples/image-prints-4.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="">
                    <img src="images/examples/thumbs-prints-4.jpg" alt="" /></a><br /> 
            </div>

        <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
     
     <img id="myImg" src="images/examples/thumbs-prints-5.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="79" height="79"/>

 <!-- The Modal -->
     <div id="myModal" class="modal">

 <!-- The Close Button -->
     <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

 <!-- Modal Content (The Image)  -->
     <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

 <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
     <div id="caption"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the javascript.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    modalImg.alt = this.alt;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() { 
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Here is the css code

```css
/* ------------- MODAL STARTS----------------*/
/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
    border-radius: 0px; /* changed from 5px to 0px so the thumbnails are not rounded */
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.5;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption { 
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)} 
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* ------------- MODAL ENDS ------------------*/
```

I tried to be as extensive as possible as to not have anyone confused.

Comment: I just created a fiddle from your code, where I used example pictures, so that no errors would occur: https://jsfiddle.net/mhLLjxym/. For your further development: You need to add click event handlers to your thumbnail links. This handler takes the links `href` attribute and sets it as the modals image `src`. Question: Since you're using JS, why don't you refer to a modal library or at least jQuery for easier element selection and manipulation?

Comment: For example, this might seem to be what you try to accomplish: http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/index.html